# C++ operator overloading and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

Do polymorphism and operator overloading mix together?

You can't do polymorphism without pointers, as it is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223613/c-polymorphism-without-pointers) and also you can't do operator overloading with pointers as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171630/why-isnt-operator-overloading-for-pointers-allowed-to-work).
So there really isn't any way to do this, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is. You didn't read the answers properly.

Here is a short demo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X
{
    int value;
    virtual void operator += (int x)
    {
        value += x;
    }
};

struct Y : X
{
    virtual void operator += (int x)
    {
        value *= x;
    }
};

void do_stuff(X& x)
{
    x += 10;
    cout << "Final value " << x.value << endl;
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.value = 10;
    Y y;
    y.value = 10;
    do_stuff(x);
    do_stuff(y);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not implying that this is a good idea, or that it's practical. It's simply just possible.

Answer (score 4):

In brief:

> Operator overloading is a **static** polymorphism.

Static polymorphism can be implemented using function overloading, operator overloading and `template`s.

I think you are considering dynamic polymorphism (`virtual` stuff) only.
On other hand, typically we don't see `virtual` function for overloaded operator, but still it's possible theoritically.

A correction: Runtime (dynamic) polymorphism can be done using pointer *and reference*.

Answer (score 3):

First, polymorphism works with both references and pointers.  And
operator overloading works with references.  So there's no problem at
that level.

There is a potential problem with binary operators.  Direct language
support for polymorphism on an operator only works on the left hand 
operand.  Where as for something like binary `+`, one logically would
expect double dispatch.  While this can be implemented, it is somewhat
more complex, especially if the hierarchies are open.

For operators like binary `+`, which normally return a new object, there
is also the question of the return type.  Typically, this *can't* be a
reference, since there is no object with an appropriate type to refer
to.  Patterns like the letter-envelop idiom have been developed to deal
with this, but they aren't necessarily simple, and they often have very
significant run-time overhead.  *Or* the overloaded operator returns a
special type, which only saves its arguments, and knows how to calculate
the value with the correct type when requested.

Answer (score 0):

> *You can't do polymorphism without pointers.*

This is not entirely accurate. While pointers are commonly used when dealing with polymorphism, it's not a strict requirement. Polymorphism can be achieved using references and objects as well.

Also, operator overloading can indeed be performed with pointers. You can overload operators for classes that involve pointers or use pointers as parameters in overloaded operator functions.

Answer (score -2):

Operator overloading in C++ can involve both runtime polymorphism and compile-time polymorphism, depending on how it is implemented.

1. **Compile-Time Polymorphism:**
   Many operator overloads are resolved at compile time. This includes operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` when used with user-defined types (such as class objects). The compiler generates code for the specific operation based on the type of operands during compilation.

   ```cpp
   class Complex {
   public:
       Complex operator+(const Complex& other) const {
           Complex result;
           result.real = this->real + other.real;
           result.imaginary = this->imaginary + other.imaginary;
           return result;
       }
   private:
       double real;
       double imaginary;
   };
   ```

   In this example, the `+` operator is overloaded for the `Complex` class. The compiler generates code for the addition operation at compile time based on the types of the operands.
2. **Runtime Polymorphism:**
   Operator overloading can also involve runtime polymorphism when it is combined with virtual functions. For example, when you overload the `<<` operator for output streaming and use it with polymorphic classes, the specific function to call is determined at runtime.

   ```cpp
   class Shape {
   public:
       virtual void draw() const {
           // Base class implementation
       }
   };

   class Circle : public Shape {
   public:
       void draw() const override {
           // Derived class implementation
       }
   };

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Shape& shape) {
       shape.draw();  // Calls the appropriate draw() based on the object's actual type
       return os;
   }
   ```

   In this example, the `<<` operator is overloaded for the base class `Shape`, and the `draw` function is called. The actual function to execute is determined at runtime based on the type of the object.

So, while some operator overloads are resolved at compile time for specific types, others can involve runtime polymorphism when used with polymorphic classes and virtual functions. The key is to understand the specific context and how the operator overloads are implemented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy