# Addition operator overload for pointers to nested classes

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, inner-classes, friend-function

I am working on a linked list class which contains a private nested node class. I want to advance n nodes forward in my list by using the overloaded addition operator but clang is giving me the error "overloaded 'operator+' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)". I thought that the implicit this parameter disappeared when you declared it as a friend function.

First is my header file

```
 template <class T>
 class List
    {

  private:

    class ListNode
    {
      public:

        ListNode();


        ListNode(const T& ndata);


        friend ListNode* operator+(const ListNode* &node, int n);

        ListNode* next;

        ListNode* prev;

    };

  public:
    friend ListNode* operator+(const ListNode* &node, int n);
```

and my implementation is as follows:

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::ListNode* List<T>::ListNode::operator+(const ListNode* &node, int n)
{
    ListNode* current = node;

    while (n--){
        if (current->next != 0)
            current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that dupe was not right.  Reopened.

Comment: A friend function isn't really a member, so you cannot define it out of line this way. Really the only sensible way of defining such functions is inline.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the problem with what you're trying to do is that it's oveloading an operator on pointers. This is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171630/why-isnt-operator-overloading-for-pointers-allowed-to-work). Simplifying your code as much as possible for the point, the following does not build:

```
class foo{};

foo *operator+(foo *, int) {
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {}
```

The attempt gives:

```
$ g++ gl.cpp 
gl.cpp:5:26: error: ‘foo* operator+(foo*, int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
 foo *operator+(foo *, int) {
```

---

If you really want to use `operator+`, the simplest way might be to use the member operator form:

```
template<class T>
class List {
    class ListNode {        ...
    public:
        ListNode &operator+(int n) {
            ListNode *current = this;

            while (n--)
               if (current->next != 0)
                   current = current->next;

           return *current;
        }
    };
    ...
};
```

However, this is a bit misleading, as you're not actually adding an integer to the node, but rather getting a next node. A `next` method is probably clearer:

```
template<class T>
class List {
    class ListNode {        ...
    public:
        ListNode *next(int n) {
            ListNode *current = this;

            while (n--)
                if (current->next != 0)
                   current = current->next;

            return current;
        }
    };
    ...
};
```

Comment: I meant to put node instead of this but I am still getting the same error, I am confused as to how to define it as a free function/ what that means.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, overloading operators on pointers is problematic, and again, the easiest thing to do would be make `operator+` a member function. However, there is a way to get the behavior you want...

The trick is to wrap the pointer in an object that acts like a pointer (commonly known as an [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)).

A working example to demonstrate:

```
class List {
    struct Node {
        Node* next; int data;
    };
    Node* m_head{0};

public:
    // the fake pointer type.
    struct Iter {
        Iter(Node* initial = 0)
            : m_base(initial) {}
        Node* operator->()
        { return m_base; }
        bool operator!=(const Iter& other) const
        { return m_base != other.m_base; }
    private:
        Node* m_base;
    };

    // get head as fake pointer.
    Iter head()
    { return m_head; }
    void push_front(const int&);
};

void List::push_front(const int& x)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->data = x;
    n->next = m_head; m_head = n;
}

// non-member operator.
List::Iter operator+(List::Iter i, int count)
{
    for ( ; count > 0 && i != 0; count-- )
        i = i->next;
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    List list;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        list.push_front(i);
    for ( auto i = list.head(); i != 0; i = i+1 )
        std::cout << i->data << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For a more advanced example see [here](https://ideone.com/a9Nsmj).

Comment: Good use of iterators!

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks!